# React uses Garbage Collector too much and slows down my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, garbage-collection

I am building a app. and I came to a point where i need to render about 1000 complex components, one after another. Here is the code that does this:

```
function App() {

    var [records, setRecords] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
        fetch(api + sessionStorage.getItem("batch") +"/" + sessionStorage.getItem("page"))
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setRecords(data);
        });
    } , [] )

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <PrimarySearchAppBar />
            <Toolbar />{" "}{/* removing this will cause an overlay between the first card and the AppBar */}
                {records.map((record) => {
                    return(
                        <RowCard
                            key={record.code}
                            str={record.str}
                            code={record.code}
                            translateButton={false}
                            saveButton={true}
                            val={record[languageCode]}
                        />
                    );                    
                })}
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
}


export default App;
```

The "records" variable holds an array with 1000 objects, with 4 fields for each object
The problem is, when react tries to render these components, there is a big delay. After some debugging, i noticed that there is a big time gap between the "setRecords(data)" statement and the actual render of the  components.

Later, i found out this:
[image: screenshot]

And it goes on and on with the "Minor GC" things.
The "Promise Callback" that's on the big yellow bar refers to my "setRecords(data)" statement.

Comment: This isn't a garbage collection issue. This is just what happens when you render lots and lots of components. At the end of the day, rendering 1,000 things takes time. That's why concepts like pagination, or loading in batches and fetching another batch when they scroll to the bottom are often used. The only 2 solutions are either make your `RowCard` component as lightweight as possible so rendering 1,000 of them is not so intense, or render your rows in batches

Comment: At the end of the day, you can't fit 1,000 rows on a single screen anyway, so rendering them all at once is a waste

Comment: @Jayce444 I agree with everything you said, but i don't see a reason for such a slow render. I can easily make it run a lot faster with the ways you suggested, but i am just curious why it takes so much time. Thanks for the reply anyway!

Comment: @Jayce444 Plus, rendering these components statically is almost instant, so i don't see a reason for React to take about 10 seconds.

Comment: Yes but rendering things dynamically vs. statically is not the same at all in React. With static, it just straight out paints it all to the screen. With your dynamic method, once you put the results into the state it has to recreate the virtual DOM with all the new rows, loop through all those elements, comparing them all to the existing DOM, then update the DOM for each of those rows. THEN it can paint it on the screen. I'm not sure why it takes *that* much longer, 1,000 doesn't seem super high number. But yeah, just wanted to say `static !== dynamic` for rendering, dynamic has more going on

Comment: @Jayce444 you are totally right, but as i said, 10 seconds is way too much.